# Remove Outliers from a Multitrace in PYMC3

Tags: bayesian, outliers, pymc3

I have a model which has 3 parameters A, n, and Beta.
I did a Bayesian analysis using pymc3 and got the posterior distributions of the parameters in a multitrace called "trace". Is there any way to remove the outliers of A (and thus the corresponding values of n and Beta) from the multitrace?

Comment: Is there literature that justifies such a procedure? Bayesians usually report intervals and sample medians, so not sure why this would be needed.

Comment: I wanna do a two steps sequential Bayesian. There are a few datapoints in the first posterior that make the second posterior strange.  Does it make sense to remove the outliers of the first posterior to get a better second posterior? My model has two dependent parameters. I guess the outliers are because of the dependency between the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Stating that specific values of A are outliers implies that you have enough "domain expertise" to know that the ranges where these values fall into have very low probability of occurence in the experiment/system you are modelling.

You could therefore narrow your chosen prior distribution for A, such that these "outliers" remain in the tails of the distribution.

Reducing the overall model entropy with such informative prior's choice is risky in a way but can be considered as a valid approach if you know that values within these specific ranges just do not happen in real-life experiments.

Once the Bayes rule applied, your posterior distribution will put a lot less weight on these ranges and should better reflect the actual system behaviour.